# How can I fix error in html2canvas library

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I was using html2canvas to convert an image in base 64 and send it through PHP and thus store it as a Blob, at first it worked correctly and when I decoded it it showed me the image, but now it shows me this error in the library and I don't know why it happens.

The error is the following:

```js
documentClone.replaceChild(documentClone.adoptNode(cloner.documentElement), documentClone.documentElement);
```

When I execute the event to take the capture of my html, I get an error in the library code, and my code sends me a base64 image but it does not exist, because the library did not take any capture of my html.

This is my javascript with which I send the image in base64

```js
    html2canvas(document.body).then(function (canvas){

        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*10000);
        ajax.open("POST", "save-any.php", true);
        ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        ajax.send("num=" + num + "&image=" + canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.9));


    });
}
```

What happens to me is that the library does not save me any image but it generates a url that does not lead to any image.

Comment: can you give the error here in your qus? all this information is not sufficient.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I just edited the question

Comment: What is `documentClone` ?

Comment: @Peterrabbit Documentclone is the line that throws me the html2canvas Js error

Comment: @JuanManuel Yes but I mean, where is supposed to be defined the `documentClone` object ?

Comment: @Peterrabbit Well, that one always jumps to me and from the library, and as such in the documentation a use of the DocumentClone is not requested

Comment: Maybe could be useful to give a little more context, like how are declared `documentClone`, `cloner` etc. When you say "the error is the following", you are talking about this error right ? `"ReferenceError: documentClone is not defined"` (this is the error we get in the snippet)

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that document.body is probably undefined.  Use chrome Deb tools and put a break on html2canvas(document.body).then(function and inspect value of document.body.

I have also seen this error when the element sent to html2canvas is not a single element/node but rather an array of nodes.